# Test converted int to char if it is number c++

Tags: c++, char, int

I would like to know how to test if a char is a number. An int has been converted to char and later on I want to see if this char is a number.

```
int num = 2;
char number = '2';
char num2 = (char)num;
cout << "Non comverted: " << number << " " << num2 << endl;
cout << "comverted: " << static_cast<int>(number) << " " << static_cast<int>(num2) << endl;
if (isdigit(number))
  cout << "number" << endl;
else if (isdigit(num2))
  cout << "num2" << endl;
else cout << "none" << endl;
```

when I run this the second if should also be able to relate to true.

The reason why I want to be able to do this is because I store a lot of different values into a char array and would later like to know when something is a number or not.

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually converting `num` to a number. Your line 3 basically results in:

```
char num2 = (char)2;
```

The ASCII character with decimal value 2 is *not* a digit. In fact, it is not printable. The easiest way to convert a single digit integer to its printable `char` is to add `'0'` to it:

```
char num2 = '0' + num;
```

The reason for this is that the character `0` is the first digit in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), directly followed by 1, 2, 3, etc...

### Edit

As [Christian Hackl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3313064/christian-hackl) points out in the comments, [c++ does not require an implementation to use ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141800/2700399), although it *is* guaranteed that the digits `0` through `9` are represented by contiguous integer values.

Comment: C++ does not require an implementation to use ASCII, although it does guarantee the range from `0` to `9` to be contiguous.

Comment: Thanx I just realised that what I wanted to do was not going to work anyway

Answer (score 0):

To translate single digits from int to ascii/utf8 characters there is a very simple conversion:

`char num2 = static_cast<char>('0' + num);`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char num2 = (char)num;
```

Does not make sense.  You're casting a 2 to a char which will give you ASCII code for STX, a special character (http://www.asciitable.com/).

You probably want this:

```
char num2 = '0' + num;
```

What that does is give you a character counted from ASCII '0', so it will work up to 9, after which you will get other characters as seen in the ASCII table.